# Proof Verification: Gaussian Integers are countably infinite

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

The set of all Gaussian integers, $\mathbb Z[i]$, is defined as,
$\mathbb Z[i] = \{a + ib : a, b ∈ \mathbb Z\}$.

Prove that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a countably infinite set

Proof: The set $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite as there exists a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

We'll define a function $\phi : \mathbb Z[i] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$\phi(a+ib)= (a,b)$

We show this is 1-1 and onto.

Assume $\phi(a+ib) =\phi(c+id)$

Then $(a,b) = (c,d)$

$\Rightarrow$ $a = c$ and $b =d$

$\Rightarrow$ $a+ib$ = $c+id$

Hence, $\phi$ is 1-1

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$
Then $(a,b)$ belong to $\operatorname{range}(\phi)$ by how our function is defined.

Then $\phi$ is onto.

This implies that the set of all Gaussian integers is countably infinite.

Can anyone please verify this? Also, is there a better way to show surjectivity? Thanks

Comment: As long as you can assume that $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is countably infinite, then this proof works.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct, provided that you're permitted to take "$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite" as proven - this isn't obvious from just the definition of "countably infinite", so it deserves proof.

Your surjectivity argument is weak, though - "Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$; Then $(a,b)$ belongs to the range of $\phi$ by how our function is defined" is basically just saying "$\phi$ is surjective because of how we defined it", which isn't so much a "proof" as an "assertion".

Instead, I would say this: Let $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. By the definition of $\phi$, $\phi(a + bi) = (a,b)$,  so $(a,b)$ is in the range of $\phi$. Thus $\phi$ is surjective.

The difference is that this way, you're explicitly demonstrating that $(a,b)$ is indeed in the range of $\phi$, rather than just claiming it.